# Quadrotor Path Planning with OMPL

Tags: ros, quadcopter, navigation, 3d-navigation, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to find a way to do 3D path planning for a quadrotor. This is a custom built quadrotor that will be controlled using mavlink (hopefully!) so not one of the ones already documented on this site. The only info I can find on 3d path planning seems to be for jointed arms on a fixed base (PR2 or similar). Is there any way I could use the 3D_navigation stack or even arm_navigation stack and adapt it for a quadrotor somehow? I have found a URDF quadrotor model in the asctec_drivers stack so was wondering if this would be useful at all.

I am using a kinect+RGBDSLAM to give a position estimate and an octomap of the surroundings. Ultimately I'd like to be able to visualise the quadcopter in RViz and set position goals, and for a collision free path to be planned.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

James,

Cambridge University Quadrotor Project

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12800/quadrotor-path-planning-with-ompl/) by [jwrobbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1711/jwrobbo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2012-01-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you know already this, but...recently prof. Roy et. al have been published a article about the Quadrotor planning. The paper calls "Polynomial Trajectory Planning for Quadrotor Flight" (I can't post links yet)

---

Originally posted by [Herick](https://answers.ros.org/users/4476/herick/) with karma: 16 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-08-24**:
I m reading that paper and I find it very interesting. Did you know whether those  functions have been already implemented in ROS?
Thanks